# Django - get all connected with M2M entries?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Having that simplified model:

```
subproducts = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

and data like this:

- Product 1

  - SubP 1
  - SubP 2
- Product 2

  - SubP 3
  - SubP 4
- Product 3

  - SubP 5
  - SubP 6

Let's say Product 1-3 are main products, SubP* are sub products.
Having a tuple with IDs of Product 1 and Product 3: (1, 3)

I want to get all of theirs subproducts, so my query should return (SubP 1, SubP 2, SubP 5, SubP 6)

How to write that query? I could loop list and make 1 query per product, but a list with 1000 objects would kill my DB.
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    subproducts = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

The query would be:

```
sub_products = MyModel.objects.filter(mymodel__id__in=[1, 3]).distinct()
```

Of if you have access to a list of the objects,

```
sub_products = MyModel.objects.filter(mymodel__in=[<object_list>]).distinct()
```

More [info on M2M relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) (read up on: `Reverse m2m queries are supported (i.e., starting at the table that doesn’t have a ManyToManyField):`)